# Can't Insert to Database with Mapped Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 code-first approach and I have the following action controller method to insert master-detail entries:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( Facturas_prueba facturas_prueba, List<FacturasDetalle_prueba> detalle)
{
    if (detalle != null && detalle.Count > 0 ) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= detalle.Count-1; i++) {
            detalle[i].folio = facturas_prueba.folio;

        ModelState["detalle[" + i + "].folio"].Errors.Clear(); //Elimina los errores de validaciones del modelo porque ya asignamos manualmente el folio
    }
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("folio", "No asignó ningun detalle para el folio"); //Agrega un error de modelo al diccionario de ModelState
}

if (ModelState.IsValid) //Si el estado del model es valido (Todas las validaciones correctas)
{
    db.Database.Log = Logger;
    db.Facturas_prueba.Add(facturas_prueba);
    db.FacturasDetalle_prueba.AddRange(detalle); //AddRange sirve para agregar collecciones
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

ViewBag.almacen = new SelectList(db.CATALMA, "COD_ALM", "NOM_ALM", facturas_prueba.almacen);
ViewBag.cliente = new SelectList(db.CATCTES, "COD_CTE", "NOM_CTE", facturas_prueba.cliente);
ViewBag.usuario = new SelectList(db.FACPARU, "cod_usu", "cod_Alm", facturas_prueba.usuario);
ViewBag.plaza = new SelectList(db.PLAZAS, "PLAZA", "LAST_COD_CTE", facturas_prueba.plaza);
return View(facturas_prueba);
```

This usually works when using default way of EF, However, now I'm trying to use a stored procedures to insert (only that for the moment) in each table, I get an exception at `db.SaveChanges()`:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code
>
> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I mapped the stored procedure like this, don't know if I'm missing something. The name on the fields and parameters are the same:

```
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Facturas_prueba>()
                .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
                s.Insert(i => i.HasName("nueva_factura") ));

...
modelBuilder.Entity<FacturasDetalle_prueba>()
                .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
                s.Insert(i => i.HasName("nuevo_factura_detalle")));
```

This is driving me crazy, database-first approach was a lot easier than this.
Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I add one of the store procedures before the change that works in the answer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nueva_factura(
    @folio varchar(10),
    @fecha datetime,
    @almacen varchar(10),
    @cliente varchar(10),
    @plaza varchar(10),
    @usuario varchar(10),
    @id_factura int = 0 OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO Facturas_prueba 
    VALUES(@folio, @fecha, @almacen, @cliente, @plaza, @usuario)

    SET @id_factura = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found that adding a **SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()** statement to the identity columns in the stored procedures fixed the problem:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE nueva_factura(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @folio varchar(10),
    @fecha datetime,
    @almacen varchar(10),
    @cliente varchar(10),
    @plaza varchar(10),
    @usuario varchar(10),
    @id_factura int = 0 --OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO Facturas_prueba VALUES(
        @folio,@fecha,@almacen,@cliente,@plaza,@usuario
    )

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id_factura
END
GO
```

Any clarification in comments about why this is required for an Insert will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  Adding `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS MyId` did it for me.

The reason this was necessary, at least for me, is when entity framework imported the stored procedure, it expected a result of MyId....

I originally had `return SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, which resulted in a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and the error `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).`

When I changed the return in my stored procedure to `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` then I got the error message that the column was not mapped correctly.

With the full `SELECT ... AS MyId` it worked.

Here's a trimmed screenshot from the insert mapping I had:
[image: Column binding for mapped sproc]